# How can I 'flip' the orientation of category fields and drop data fields in Visual Studio 2005?

Tags: visual-studio-2005

I'm new to visual studio and have a chart with data but the output looks a little wonky and I can't figure out how to rotate the way the data at the bottom of the chart looks.

For example, i'd want to go from:
    Some text

to:

```
t
x
e
t

e
m
o
S
```

something like that. Thanks for your help

Comment: Are you talking about changing the orientation of labels on a chart on the X-axis? Edit your question to show your code.

Comment: I had gone to this site and used one of these format keys in the properties section when I right-click on the chart:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx

Comment: aw come on(To whoever thumb downed my question)! It wasn't necessary to mark my question down. I told you i'm new to this. ugh. Way to welcome people

Comment: @Shades: Welcome to Super User! Here, get an upvote. If you found the solution, you could place it as an answer and even accept it to gain some additional reputation for showing us the solution to the problem you are experiencing. This could in the end help someone else also experiencing the same problem...